# How to use long file names on Teensy/Arduino SD Card Reader

Tags: arduino, teensy

Does anyone know if there is a way to get Arduino SD card readers to work with long files names (bigger than the 8.3 filename format)? I am currently trying read files from a Teensy 3.5 using the standard Arduino SD card library, and the file fails to open whenever I use longer file names. Is this an inherent hardware limitation, or is it simply a software limitation? If I could implement this, it would greatly simplify my code and would improve the user experience significantly.

Comment: Could you post your code and the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...I looked into the "SD.h" Arduino library noticed that the library is only designed for small file names since many of the array declarations specifically limit the name of the file size(e.g. char _name[13]). I found that using the "SdFat.h" library works with large filenames and completely solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ... using the standard Arduino SD card library ...

Here's your problem. This library is intended to work with an 328 based Uno with limited RAM. If you study the library and the FAT structure, you can find out where the long filename is located...